# How can I make texture and material look like an MRI?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I have been using blender for years but only for pretty basic modeling and animation. I am trying to imitate the look of an MRI scan.

Does anyone have any suggestions for achieving this material/texture?

Also advice on how to model one of these images?

Thank you in advanced!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would start by making various mixes of SSS and Transparency shaders, at different densities. I would also consider baking an AO map and then adding contrast to it to emphasize dark pits and whatnot. You might also experiment with volume shaders.

Comment: In my opinion you should do a mix of SSS and absorption shader. Apply a layer weight as factor.

Comment: What's the question here exactly? How to model something like these images which would let you animate the slice motion, or simply make a static image (without possibility to animation the motion of the camera moving into the object) .