# Render Object with CT scan effect?

Tags: materials

Is there any addons or tricks that I can use to turn my object into a CT Scan result? meaning they looks like this from all angles: 
[image]

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Related: [How can I make texture and material look like an MRI?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43045/how-can-i-make-texture-and-material-look-like-an-mri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Volumetrics

X-ray images can be simulated with the use of a quite simple volumetric shader in conjuction with a *very good* modeling.

The information stored in such imagesis basically just one: how fare the X ray radiation goes far? The variations is caused by the different nature of materials. Each one of them let the ray pass more or less.

In Cycles engine, there is no X-ray radiations, but we can simulate the behaviour with light. The energy of the source will be absorption by passing through a volumetric shader like the following.

[image]

The hard part is that you must:

1. model everything with it's own, real, thickness in order to achieve a correct absorption calculation
2. create a different volumetric shader for each kind of material of your scene (one for glass, one for metal, one for filament...) and estimate the light absorption value (driven by the Density parameter).

   The model in the above picture comes from a collection of CC0 Bulbs on [Blendwap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/search?keywords=bulb&is_fan_art=1&blend_license=CC-0&render_engine=&sort=downloads&direction=desc)